# rails ajax currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, currency

How to create the following:

I want make ajax currency switcher with rails

[usd|rub|eur]

In db I have only usd value

What gem suitable for this purpose? Or maybe browser-side solution is better?

Who has experience please give me advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we use the [Money Gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) you can specify a Money column in your model to make the handling easier.

```
# Get exchange rates
Money.default_bank = ExchangeBankWhichScrapesXeDotCom.new
# new money object in USD
usd = Money.new(1000, "USD")
# exchange to rubel
rub = usd.exchange_to("RUB")
```